# DataTables js How to reduce the width of the entire table

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am using DataTables with AJAX datasource, by default there is alot of columns, so the page will automatically need to scroll right.

Below is the picture:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to reduce the width of the entire table manually perhaps using CSS?

I tried doing the below:

```
<section id="ticket-table-container">
    <table id="tickets-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerCompanyName</th>
                <th>CustomerContactName</th>
                <th>CustomerId</th>
                <th>CustomerRegion</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>LastUpdatedBy</th>
                <th>LastUpdatedTime</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>TicketChannel</th>
                <th>TicketCreated</th>
                <th>TicketSLAExpiry</th>
                <th>TicketSeverity</th>
                <th>TicketStatus</th>
                <th>TicketType</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</section>
```

Putting the table inside the `section` and manually changing the width of the `section`. However, that does not help.

I know I can specify `responsive` with this code below:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tickets-table").DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
```

However I wonder if it is possible to not use `responsive` and somehow just manually change the width so that the the table width is shortened so that the page does not need to scroll right?

Comment: The own solution is specific width of all `<th>`

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that your table should stretch to the available space in the parent container when you do `style="width:100%"` on your `<table>` tag. Remove it to make the table use the required space.

Also, please avoid inline CSS styling, HTML should be used for structure and semantic, while CSS is used for presentation.